# What are the advantages to booking a hotel via an online travel agent, rather than directly?

Tags: bookings, hotels

What are the advantages to booking a hotel via an online travel agent, rather than booking it directly with the hotel?

Is it price, trust, convenience or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this appears to  be a survey, ratehr than a genuine travel question.

Comment: All of the things you've mentioned and more; for example, many companies require that business travel be arranged through their official travel agency. No one is requiring you to use a travel agent for personal travel if you don't see the advantage to one, but clearly, the industry exists because there are people who do.